# how to refer to return value of a function from outside in Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I've been making dynamic dropdown box that each option has the table's name of BigQuery and I want to use return value (list) that is made inside .then method in function listTables(). However it seems not to work well . I'm new to Js so could you give any tips ?? Thank you so much.

```
function listTables() {
    const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

    const bigquery = new BigQuery({
      projectId: 'test_project',
    });

    const list = [];
    bigquery
        .dataset("test_table")
        .getTables()
        .then(results => {
            const tables = results[0];
            tables.forEach(table => list.push(table.id));
            return console.log(list);←I want to use this list outside a function 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
}
listTables();

// select tag
let slt = document.getElementById("slt");
addTables(slt);

// return data 
function getList() {
  return new Promise(function (onFulliflled, onRejected) {
    onFulliflled(list);
  });
}

function addTables(slt) {
  getList()
    .then((list) => {
      for (item of list) {
        // optionを作成
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = item;
        option.value = item;

        // optionの追加
        slt.appendChild(option);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("error", err);
    });
}
```

```
.then(results => {
            const tables = results[0];
            tables.forEach(table => list.push(table.id));
            return console.log(list);
        })

RESULT 
[ 'test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3' ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in multiple ways.

Using calllback

```
function listTables(callback) {
    //...

        .then(results => {
            const tables = results[0];
            tables.forEach(table => list.push(table.id));
            callback(list);
        })
    //...
}

listTables(function(list){

});
```

Using promise or async/await

```
function listTables() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    //...

        .then(results => {
            const tables = results[0];
            tables.forEach(table => list.push(table.id));
            resolve(list);
        })
    //...
    });
}

// Promise
listTables().then(function(list){

});

//Async/await
var list = await listTables();
```

For the await to work you also need to run in within an async function. For example wrap it in async iife.

```
(async function(){
    var list = await listTables();
})();
```

I don't use await myself so this is just from top of my head and might need some changes.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will try to use callback as following your code .